# How to click button with id=submit in iframe website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I've got something like this in my index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<iframe id="main" src="https://forexample.com"></iframe>
```

jQuery.js code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#main').load(function(){
    $('submit').click();
  });
});
```

I want automatically click submit button while window page is loading.

Could you help me or give me some tips?

Best regards

Tom

Comment: WHy you have two jQuery files there? Also what issue you are facing? And what is there inside iframe? Put that content too

Comment: Inside the iframe i've got another website, barracuda. There is only 1 jquery file, another 2 is a main file for jquery.

Comment: The question is, why i can't click the button :P

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11801977/2968762

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#main').load(function(){
    $(this).find('input#Submit').click();
  });
});
```

I've used `jQuery find` method to get the `id=submit`

Assumption `<input name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Sign in" class="cui-field-submit cui-field-align-right" data-action="" data-confirmation="" type="submit">`

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Still not working, fully code of button is:


<input name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Sign in" class="cui-field-submit cui-field-align-right" data-action="" data-confirmation="" type="submit">

Comment: @IamLow `id="Submit"` and in the `JavaScript` it's `#submit` that the problem. Let me update the answer

Comment: Still nothing, maybe the problem is in HTML document, maybe should i put the script href in other place? Hmmm.. When I'm in my index.html i can't see the code of website in iframe. What do u think about that?

Comment: Try `$(this).contents().find('input#Submit').click();`

Comment: Still nothing. Maybe it would be easier to make some scripts in node.js or php to do different operations.

I need to log in on one website by clicking submit, copy url adress, paste it in another website and click another one button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#main').load(function(){
    var document = $(this).contents(); // To fetch contents within iframe
    document.find('#submit').click();
  });
});
```

Comment: Nothing, maybe something is blocking actions like this on website in iframe.. Some filters, idk.

Comment: Then I think you are facing **cross origin error**, something like: "Failed to ... Blocked a frame with origin "http://xxxx from accessing a cross-origin frame.
"